# Do lyophilic sols have an electrical double layer?

Tags: surface-chemistry, colloids, colligative-properties

> "There are two factors which are responsible for the stability of lyophilic sols. These factors are the charge and solvation of the colloidal particles".

*Quoted from NCERT book of OC*

But we studied the electrical double layer only in the case of lyophobic colloids.

## Question:

Do lyophilic colloids have an electrical double layer? If so, why?
*Also since the ions should not even have a place to stay on the particles as they are already solvated by the dispersed medium molecules.*

So where could the charge of lyophilic colloids come from?

Comment: Begin by answering the question "what is a lyophobic colloid?" and include some examples (I encourage you also to include this information in your post)